# transform horizontal bar to vertical bar using css

Tags: html, css

Hi everyone I'm trying to change a horizontal bar to a vertical bar but I can't managed to do that.
The bar has 2 colors green and red.
It works horizontally but it shouldn't.
I hope somebody can help me with that.

HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="progress binary-progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.binary-progress {
    background: #f27271;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    float: left;
    min-height: 80%;
    width: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -moz-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg,rgba(255,255,255,.15)    25%,transparent 25%,transparent 50%,rgba(255,255,255,.15) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,.15) 75%,transparent 75%,transparent);
    -webkit-background-size: 40px 40px;
    background-size: 40px 40px;
}
.binary-progress .progress-bar {
    background-color: #92c47d;
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: where is the animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS3 `transform` to rotate the bar by 90deg.

Not sure if this is what you were looking for, but I hope it helps:

```css
.binary-progress {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: left top;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <div class="col col-4">
    <div class="progress binary-progress">
      <div class="vertical progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi thanks! your answer was very helpful however I still have a problem with your solution, if I use rotate the margin-left increases is there a solution to that? thanks

Comment: Can you be specific and mention which element's margin-left property increases?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, if I use rotate 90 deg the progress bar margin-left and top will be based on the horizontal one, not on the vertical one, as well if I use 70% width it will be based on the column width and not height, I hope you understand what i'm trying to say.

Comment: margin-left and margin-top will behave how it would behave if the progress-bar had been horizontal. You can set either, depending on where you want to move it to. It's the same with the progress width(70% here)

Comment: Also, I figured you were worried about the left margin seen on the `.binary-progress` element. I have modified the code to fix that. Please take a look.

Comment: Good to know! If the answer is satisfactory, you can mark it accepted and close the question. :)